# Add Facebook 'share' metatag to drupal

Tags: php, facebook, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am very new to drupal, and i need to know whether i can add a share button using metatags. The requirement is to display a list of links and a share button for each link beside it. This should share the page given in the link. Is this possible? If so, how? I'm currently able to add a like button using the `<fb:like></fb:like>` tag. Googling wasn't much helpful. FYI, i use drupal 7.

Thanks,
Ananth.

Comment: Instead of giving a negative, can you please explain why it was given so, it'd be much helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for adding meta tags to a drupal 7 page, you should use [drupal_add_html_head](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7)()

Here's an example for adding a description meta tag.

```
drupal_add_html_head(array(
    '#tag'          => 'meta',
    '#attributes'   => array(
        'property'  => 'description',
        'content'   => 'this is my description tag',
    )), "YOU_KEY");
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this is very much feasible.
If your link is "http://www.google.com"
and you want to share this URL on FB, this link will help you in making the link
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Similarly for Google plus - https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/
Twitter button - twitter.com/about/resources/buttons

You need to pass the URL for every tag, it will same as the Link you are building.